How can I add MultipartFile from request to an object of MimeMessageHelper via addAttachment( )?
following is my controller portion
@RequestMapping(value = "/message-for-support/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestParam("subject") @NotEmpty @NotNull String subject,
                                    @RequestParam("detail") @NotEmpty @NotNull String detail,
                                    @RequestParam("attachmentFile") MultipartFile attachmentFile) {
        return supportSideService.createSupportSideMessage(subject, detail, attachmentFile);
    }

following two are the methods of service class
public ResponseEntity<?> createSupportSideMessage(String subject, String detail, MultipartFile attachmentFile) {
        SupportSide supportSide = new SupportSide();
        try {
            supportSide.setSubject(subject);
            supportSide.setDetail(detail);
            sendSimpleMailMessage(subject, detail, attachmentFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        supportSideRepository.save(supportSide);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("message sent!!!!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

@Async
    public void sendSimpleMailMessage(String subject, String detail, MultipartFile attachmentFile) {
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setFrom(fromEmail);
            helper.setTo(to);
            helper.addAttachment(attachmentFile.getOriginalFilename(), attachmentFile);
            javaMailSender.send(message);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }

I followed the following link to try this, but it does not seem to work
text
I tried to attach the MultipartFile from request header to email.
I'm expecting to attach the MultipartFile from request header to email.

What exactly doesn't work? What error message or exception are you seeing, at what step?
